# How to change image pixels values?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, coding-style, pixel

I have an image and I want to assign different value for each pixel location (x,y) as follow:

v(x,y) = a(y^2) + b(y) + c

where a, b, and c are parameters determined empirically.

How can I do that in matlab? I mean how can I change pixels values of an image there?

Comment: Does your image `v` have a single value for each pixel, or is it 3 values, like with an RGB image?

Comment: It's 3 values, I figured out how to make it work for it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you only want to change the image values based on the y coordinate, so create a new matrix `y` like this:

```
y = (1:height)' * ones(1,width);
```

where height and width are the size of your image:

```
[height, width] = size(v);
```

then create your image `v`:

```
v = a.*(y.^2) + b.*y + c;
```

This will work if `a`, `b`, and `c` are single values or matrices with the same size as `y`.

Hopefully that is what you were asking for.

Comment: Sorry but what is hight and width? and I don't understand how is that changing the original image values?

Comment: @user2833205 height and width are your image dimensions. From your question you only appear to change `v` pixel values based on its `y` coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of image and pixel is misleading in your case (it seems you are just speaking about matrix). Try to run this code:

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3;
x = 1:100; % x and y define from 1 to the value for the size of your matrix
y = 1:100;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
```

You can then get the value V with the following code:

```
V = a * Y.^2 + b * Y + c;
```

And plot it with:

```
figure;
imagesc(V);
```

Cheers